# ClickableSpan onClickListener not being called

Tags: android, textview, clickable

I'm trying to create a `TextView` that has contains a link to open another activity. The `ClickableSpan` is not calling it's `onClickListener` however. I did search through similar questions and haven't found a solution, so I'm wondering if it's something particular with my code. I did attempt a few fixes, I read that the exact location of setting `textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()` matters. I'm wondering if the `LinkMovementMethod` is issue, since I'm not attaching a URL or anything, just another activity? I'm running this code in a ui thread within a Fragment

Here's the textview/clickable span code:

```
val message : TextView = main_activity.findViewById(R.id.message)
                    val ss = SpannableString("Not finding what you're looking for? Try refining your search, or create your own group!")
                    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
                        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                            widget.setOnClickListener {
                                Log.d("TEST","This should print but does not")
                            }
                        }

                        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                            super.updateDrawState(ds)
                            ds.isUnderlineText = true
                        }
                    }
                    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 66, 88, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                    message.isClickable = true
                    message.linksClickable = true
                    message.textSize = 23.toFloat()
                    message.highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                    message.text = ss
                    message.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
                }
```

And the textview in XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.186" />
```

Comment: Why do you call `widget.setOnClickListener` inside `onClick` method? Probably you should just put your click action (open another activity) into `onClick` method.

Comment: That was a good catch, but it actually doesn't change the outcome  - the ```onClick``` doesn't seem to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the textView clickable

```
<TextView
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:id="@+id/message"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I actually had set it progmatically in my code, you can see it underneath the ```ClickableSpan```, but I did try putting it in the XML just to be sure - no dice unfortunately.